# Allow user to execute jar file, but not to copy(read) it

Tags: permissions, chmod, restricted-access

I have interesting problem which I am not sure there is a solution for.

I need to allow a specific user to execute a Java program(jar), but not to copy(read) it. The problem is that if I give only `execute` permission to the `jar`, JVM can't run it, because it needs to read it in the first place. But if I give `read` permission on the file, then the user will be able to copy it somewhere else.

Any ideas how I can achieve the desired result?

**ADDITONAL INFO AFTER READING COMMENTS**

Per `Rinzwind` comment, I created a C wrapper and compiled it. Here is the source of the wrapper:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
   execl("/usr/bin/java",
    "/usr/bin/java",
    "-jar",
    "test.jar",
         (char*)0
    );

  /* If we get here, the exec didn't work */
  perror("Failed to execute /path/to/java");
  return 1;
}
```

Here are the current permissions of the `jar` and `compiled wrapper`:

```
-r-x------  1 jrunner  jrunner 23365202 авг  6 17:01 test.jar*
-r-s--x--x  1 jrunner  jrunner     8656 авг  9 23:54 wrapper*
```

As you see there is a user with `read` and `execute` permissions of `test.jar`. And SUID is turned on for the `wrapper` binary.

But I still get the error:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile test.jar` when I run the `wrapper` as other user

Comment: I don't think this is possible, unless maybe you write a script that runs this as another user, where said other user has read/execute permissions to the original jar file and the real user has not. Then you would probably have to configure `sudo` though to allow the real user to execute the file as the other user without password (without allowing him to acquire root privileges through `sudo` though!)... I think this will become as complicated to set up and maintain as it sounds.

Comment: I believe it is but it wont be easy: create a wrapper to start the JAR, compile the wrapper, set the wrapper to a user and group and put it outside the users reach (ie. in something like /etc/ or /bin/, set a setuid and then user "sudoers" to create an option to start this wrapper with a NOPASSWD option.  But this seems to me more for https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/  You will also need to make sure the user can not use ptrace and can not create his own swap (it will be possible to read the JAR when the file starts swapping).

Comment: Here is a starter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085748/linux-permissions-to-run-but-not-read-files and here an answer from @gilles  on a question about how to read a binary  that is sort of protected https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-can-i-analyse-an-executable-with-no-read-permission

Comment: @Rinzwind Are you talking about compiled C program? And if so, when I run the JVM within it, wouldn't the JVM again end up with the need of `read` permission on the `jar`?

Comment: That's why you use a new user and group. That user has read permissions. So your limited user will need special tools to read the file (like `ptrace` or a memory dump: create a private swap, make that one take precedence over the system swap and read the memory).

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind , could you please take a look at the updated issue description?

Comment: hmm could it be you need the full path to java.jar?

Comment: @Rinzwind, I don't think so, because I first trieed with full pah and it didnt find it, but the error was different. Also if I start the same compiled `wrapper` with `jrunner` user, then it is executed.